# Update multiple fields of a record using Linq and EF not working

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have a ridiculous problem with updating a record of SQL DB. I wrote a function which update My db using an EF data model as below:

```
public static void UpdateEventTime(int ID, int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int duration)
{
  (from e in SchedulerDatabase.Events where e.ID == ID select e).Single().Duration = duration;
  SchedulerDatabase.SaveChanges();
}
```

this works perfectly but when I try to update multiple fields like this:

```
public static void UpdateEventTime(int ID, int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int duration)
{
  Event E = (from e in SchedulerDatabase.Events where e.ID == ID select e).Single();
  E.StartDate = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0);
  E.Duration = duration;
  SchedulerDatabase.SaveChanges();
}
```

It doesn't work! But if I put a breakpoint there and run it again, It shows that EF is updated cause `E.Duration` holds the updated value(not the value in DB), but it does not update the database! What am I doing wrong? Does it update just one field?!(If I delete `E.StartDate = ...` Line it works and updates the DB) or is there any problem with datetime?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Just out of curiosity.. what are the values you have passed in for year, month, day, hour and minute? Could it be a case that you are passing invalid parameter values in?

**2.** I think you need to let EF know that you are making a change to the state of the object.

I don't have Visual Studio to hand but can you try the following:

```
public static void UpdateEventTime(int ID, int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int duration)
{
  Event E = (from e in SchedulerDatabase.Events where e.ID == ID select e).Single();
  E.StartDate = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0);
  E.Duration = duration;
  SchedulerDatabase.Entry(E).State = EntityState.Modified;
  SchedulerDatabase.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: No I did that before updating multiple fields of a record like this:
'Contact c = (from contact in SchedulerDatabase.Contacts where contact.ID == ID select contact).Single();
            c.FirstName = firstName;
            c.LastName = lastName;
            c.Gender = gender;
            c.FatherName = fathersName;
            c.NationalNumber = nationalNumber;
            c.Photo = photo;
            c.Birthdate = pc.ToDateTime(persianYear, persianMonth, persianDay, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            SchedulerDatabase.SaveChanges();'
but I don't know thy it is not working here!

Comment: Just out of curiosity.. what are the values you have passed in for year, month, day, hour and minute? Could it be a case that you are passing invalid parameter values in?